# Accessing variables in other ViewControllers Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, variables, viewcontroller

I have a problem I can't seem to solve myself, I have two view controllers, the first one contains three variables that stores integers.  On my second view controller I have 3 sliders which manipulates a label under each slider with a number.

I want the numbers from these 3 sliders to replace the numbers that were set in the three variables on my first view controller when I click a button on the second view controller but when I when I type in the variable name it doesn't show up in the second view controller?

Can somebody explain what I may be doing wrong as I thought the variables were public and globally accessible throughout my app but I'm struggling to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is some of my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var timer = Timer()
    
    var softTime = 180
    var mediumTime = 300
    var hardTime = 600
    
    var chosenTime = 0
```

I want softTime, mediumTime & hardTime to be changed from the button in the next view controller:

```
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var softLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var softSliderValue: UISlider!
    @IBAction func softSlider(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let currentValue = Int(softSliderValue.value)
        
        softLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
        
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mediumLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mediumSliderValue: UISlider!
    @IBAction func mediumSlider(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let currentValue = Int(mediumSliderValue.value)
        
        mediumLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
        
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var hardLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hardSliderValue: UISlider!
    @IBAction func hardSlider(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let currentValue = Int(hardSliderValue.value)
        
        hardLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func setTimesButton(_ sender: Any) {
        

        
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
}
```

Comment: post your code.  Also did you declare a variable in your second ViewController to reference the first ViewController?

Comment: Use protocol to pass data from second view controller to first view controller

Comment: @f_qi hi thanks for the prompt reply. I'll post my code once back at the computer. No I've not referenced it. Have you an example I could follow?

Comment: Use delegate to pass data from second vc to first vc

Comment: @AnilKumar is that as simple as ctrl dragging from the second VC to the little circle at the top of the first VC?

Comment: @Futhark try the solution , as for now it is in swift 2.2 , make changes according to swift 3

Answer (score 0):

```
//in Second VC
protocol PassDataDelegte: class {

    func your method(first: String, second: String, third: String)
}

weak var delegate: PassDataDelegte?

func youction button() {

delegate?.yourmethod(first, timeString: second, third: date)
}



// in First VC
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "DeadlineSegue" {
            let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! YourSecondViewController
            dvc.delegate = self
        }
    }


    extension YourFirstViewController: PassDataDelegte {
    func sendDateTime((first: String, second: String, third: String) {
      print(first)
      print(second)
      print(third)
    }
```